# How can I install profiling libraries in Haskell when using cabal, in Ubuntu 14.04.5?

Tags: ubuntu, haskell, profiling, ubuntu-14.04, glut

I have a Haskell project for which I would like to obtain the stack trace when an exception is thrown. I am using GHC 8.0.2 and the module `Graphics.UI.GLUT`, where the version of GLUT is 2.7.0.11.

I have installed the module using cabal.

[This page from the official website](https://wiki.haskell.org/Debugging#Stack_trace) suggests that I compile using the `-prof` flag. However, I get the following error

```
 Failed to load interface for ‘Graphics.UI.GLUT’
 Perhaps you haven't installed the profiling libraries for package ‘GLUT-2.7.0.11’?
 Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS. Using [this link](http://packages.ubuntu.com/cgi-bin/search_packages.pl?keywords=glut&searchon=names&subword=1&version=breezy&release=all), I decided to run

```
sudo apt-get install libghc-glut-prof
```

However, this did not solve the problem. How can I solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: It should have solved the problem if you are really using `Graphics.UI.GLUT` installed from Ubuntu (via the `libghc-glut-dev` package). Are you sure you did not install `glut` via `cabal` (`cabal install glut`) as well?

Comment: @JoachimBreitner I think I installed using cabal. What should be the solution in this case please?

Answer (score 4):

Running

```
sudo apt-get install libghc-glut-prof
```

is the right thing to do if you indeed use the Debian package to get `Graphics.UI.GLUT`.

If you have installed the `glut` package with `cabal` yourself, e.g. with

```
cabal install glut
```

or some other package that pulls in `glut`, then you can run

```
cabal install --enable-library-profiling --force-reinstall glut
```

(or whatever other package you installed that pulled in `glut`) to rebuild with profiling enabled.

None of this is specific to `glut`.

Comment: Thank you! This is going to take some time for me it seems, because each package says that another package needs its profiling libraries to be installed first. Will accept when done.

Comment: You can also just nuke `~/.ghc/` and start fresh. That’s probably what I would do…